# How to insert data in database with ASP.Net vb .mdf

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2008

The add and insert function of my application doesn't work. I have no idea what I did wrong. Can you find any error? Please help!

Here is my code:

```
Protected Sub btnConfirm_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnConfirm.Click



    Dim connString As String
    connString = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=E:\\boomwebsite\App_Data\playaazaleaDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

    Dim myConnection As New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connString)
    Try
        myConnection.Open()

        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO reservations(fname, lname, contactnumber, amenities, date, price, status, statuscount) VALUES (@FNAME, @LNAME, @CONTACT, @AMENITIES, @DATE, @PRICE, @STATUS, @STATUSCOUNT)"
        cmd.Connection = myConnection
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FNAME", txtboxFname.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LNAME", txtboxLname.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CONTACT", txtboxContact.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AMENITIES", DropDownListAmenities.SelectedItem.Value)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATE", txtboxDate.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PRICE", txtboxPrice.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STATUS", txtboxStatus.text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STATUS2", txtboxStatus2.text)

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Response.Redirect("bookedreservations.aspx")

    Catch ex As Exception
        Label1.text = "Error Inserting Data ..."
    Finally
        myConnection.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Need more information - do you get any errors, exceptions, database errors?

Comment: nope, it just goes straight to the

 Catch ex As Exception
        Label1.text = "Error Inserting Data ..."
    Finally
        myConnection.Close()
    End Try

Comment: You're positive that it doesn't get inserted into the database? The Response.Redirect will always throw a ThreadAbortException exception, which will always make the label say "Error Inserting Data".

Comment: yes i am, it also does't redirect to the bookedreservations page,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, having an exception handler that writes out .. "Error Inserting Data"... without telling you what is the error seems to be a little useless, at least write

```
Catch ex As Exception
    Label1.text = "Error Inserting Data ... " & ex.Message
...
```

that will show what's going wrong with your query.

However there is a big suspect in that query. The word Date is a reserved keyword in almost any database system. If you want to use it then enclose in square brackets

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO reservations(fname, lname, " & _ 
     "contactnumber, amenities, [date], price, status, statuscount) " & _
     "VALUES (@FNAME, @LNAME, @CONTACT, @AMENITIES, @DATE, " & _ 
     "@PRICE, @STATUS, @STATUSCOUNT)"
```

Another possible problem is the method AddWithValue. This method, while handy, has a dark side that you need to be fully aware when using it. It creates a parameter with a datatype that is assumed looking at the datatype of the value that you pass. In your case, for example, the `price` field should be a nvarchar field because you pass a  txtboxPrice.Text property that is a string.
It is better to use

```
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@PRICE", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(txtboxPrice.Text)
```

and so on for the other parameters.

Comment: this came out. so now what do i do next?
Error Inserting Data ...An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file E:\\boomwebsite\App_Data\playaazaleaDatabase.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

Comment: Try removing the User Instance from the connection string